# How to enable GZIP compression in WebLogic on EAR files?

Tags: java, weblogic, gzip, weblogic12c, java-ee-8

I have an EAR app that send large response from my web service. You can enable GZIP in weblogic in the weblogic.xml file as outlined [here][1] and [here][2]. By adding `gzip-compression` tag to the `container-descriptor`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <container-descriptor>
        <gzip-compression>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <min-content-length>1</min-content-length>
            <content-type>text/html</content-type>
            <content-type>text/xml</content-type>
            <content-type>application/json</content-type>
        </gzip-compression>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

The thing is that I do not have a WAR with a weblogic.xml file but an EAR with a weblogic-application.xml.

So I added it to the `weblogic-application.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application
        xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
        
    <container-descriptor>
        <gzip-compression>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <min-content-length>4096</min-content-length>
            <content-type>text/html</content-type>
            <content-type>text/xml</content-type>
            <content-type>application/json</content-type>
        </gzip-compression>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-application>
```

If I try to add it to the weblogic-application.xml I get the following error on startup.

```
    <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
    weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error parsing META-INF/weblogic-application.xml
            at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:213)
            at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:61)
            at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:131)
            at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:91)
            at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:94)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
      <26:7> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 
      
      'fast-swap@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application 
      coherence-cluster-ref@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application osgi-framework-reference@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application resource-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application resource-env-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application ejb-reference-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application service-reference-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application message-destination-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application class-loading@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application ready-registration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application cdi-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application' 
      
      instead of 
      
      'container-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application' here in element weblogic-application@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application
            at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:249)
            at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:235)
            at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:159)
            at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:345)
            at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:307)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Can this be activated for EAR's and is there any documentation on it? Google is not much a help here

  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES532
  [2]: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WBAPP/configurewebapp.htm#WBAPP700
```

Comment: The log shows that the issue is in the weblogic-application.xml file and not in your weblogic.xml file.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin An EAR does not have a weblogic.xml file but a weblogic-application.xml. I added my weblogic-application.xml  where I added the gzip-compression tag. IntelliJ also does not recognize it and when I startup I get this error

Comment: The weblogic.xml file must be placed into your web-app (.war) in the WEB-INF folder
The weblogic-application.xml file must be placed in your ear in the META-INF folder.
Your gzip config MUST be set in your weblogic.xml file, remove it from your weblogic-application.xml file.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Thanks that works. 
Sorry for one more question
Do you know how to verify that it is in fact working? I can see if I activate this that my response has an extra response header `X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network: gzip` but the content is still json. I am expecting the content to be scrambled of some sort? I changed the Content Length to 0 and 1 and made my response very big but still it does not look like it compress anything. I also called this from a rest client. Everywhere it is called from it still gets a response but did I in fact achieve anything?